# JWT logout on Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-mvc, jwt

I would have a small problem to solve, I wrote a class for the generation and verification of a JWT token, but I have come to a crossroads: how can I invalidate the token to make a logout function? Use Spring MVC to create simple API rest to interface with an external frontend in Angular 5.

The code:

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Clock;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultClock;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SecurityUtil {

    private static final String secretKey = "secret";
    private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityUtil.class);
    private static Clock clock = DefaultClock.INSTANCE;

    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    private static Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
         Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
         if(claims != null) {
             return claims.getExpiration();
         }
         return null;
    }

    private static Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        try {
             return Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secretKey))
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.info(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }  
    }

    private static Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        if(expiration != null) {
            return expiration.before(clock.now());
        }
        return null;

    }

    private static Date calculateExpirationDate(Date createdDate) {
        return new Date(createdDate.getTime() + (60 * 15) * 1000);
    }

    public static Boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            return !isTokenExpired(token);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String generateToken(String id, String subject) {
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

        Date createdDate = clock.now();
        Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secretKey);
        Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

        return  Jwts.builder()
                .setId(id)
                .setIssuedAt(createdDate)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey)
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .compact();

        }

    public static String refreshToken(String token) {
        Date createdDate = clock.now();
        Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        claims.setIssuedAt(createdDate);
        claims.setExpiration(expirationDate);

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secretKey))
            .compact();
    }


}
```

I also noticed that after I refresh the token the past one is not invalidated.

Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have limited options with JWT, as it's a stateless token that's supposed to be kept on the client, not server, and as such, cannot be invalidated easily. You can, of course, add custom black-list for invalidated tokens on the server, but this solution won't scale well, as you'll need to distribute the black-list to all application instances (you can use any distributed cache solution for the black-list storage).

That said, it might still work reasonably well, if you combine it with a short TTL on the token itself, as you can then impose a very aggressive cleanup policy on the black-list (as there's no sense to keep entries in the black-list for longer than the token TTL), reducing the amount of data you need to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and I could not solve it. I change the expiration date to 2 minutes